# Impose response formatting as a key value string

Tags: text-formatting

Let's suppose I invoke the following command:

```
pwd && ls -l
```

and I would like to receive response in a desired format for example:

```
[CurrentDirectory=[here_result_of_pwd]] [AllDirectoriesInCurrentDirectory= 
[here_result_of ls -l command]]
```

Is there any other way to impose a desired way of formatting in Unix for this kind of result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo -e "[CurrentDirectory=[`pwd`]] [AllDirectoriesInCurrentDirectory=[`ls -l | grep -v '^total'`]]"
```

Output:

```
 [CurrentDirectory=[/home/test]] [AllDirectoriesInCurrentDirectory=[-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 17 16:50 2501254200*.nc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  118 Jul 17 12:12 ghf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  179 Aug  1 16:35 jjj
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  716 Aug  2 17:15 kk
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2527 Jul 17 15:10 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  216 Jul 17 16:28 ttt]]
```